# Extraer archivos de carpeta comprimida bash

Tags: bash, cmd, zip, .bat

estoy tratando de extraer los archivos de todas las carpetas .zip de de la carpeta c:\files

Intente con 7zip pero aún no encuentro la orden correcta para hacerlo ¿Alguien me puede orientar un poco?
Muchas gracias

Comment: Creo que a tu pregunta le falta algo mas de desarrollo consulta [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: La etiqueta dice bash, pero creo que te refieres a batch

Answer (score 0):

En teoria el comando es este

```
7z.exe e .\archivozip.zip
```

Pero tienes que tener el path si trabajas con windows. https://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-10/add-windows-path-environment-variable/